# Set a custom listener to listen throughout the whole application

Tags: android, listener, android-lifecycle

I was wondering if it's possible to have 1 listener listen for a specific event throughout the whole application.

At this moment I have created my own listener which is listening for an event to happen, however it should still listen to this event when I switch to another activity.

Comment: take a look into otto or greenrobot event bus, this is most likely the solution for you

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will have a look into this!

Comment: I've also had magnificently positive experience with EventBus, I'd gladly recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use http://square.github.io/otto/ for event listening.

This is an example of usage:

```
Bus bus = new Bus();

bus.post(new AnswerAvailableEvent(42));

@Subscribe public void answerAvailable(AnswerAvailableEvent event) {
    // TODO: React to the event somehow!
}

bus.register(this); // In order to receive events, a class instance needs to register with the bus.
```